# Which python packages would you recommend for time series analysis?

Tags: python, econometrics, eviews

I am taking a time series analysis class that uses [EViews](http://www.eviews.com/home.html). What packages in python do equivalent work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gold standard for time series analysis in Python is [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org). Pandas was originally developed at AQR to support their in-house research and has since been open-sourced. It has very high-performance implementations for data structures such as `Series`, `DataFrame`, and `Panel`.

Pandas itself is very rich. Not only does it let you create time series representations effortless, it has built-in utilities for merging time series, plotting data (requires [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org)), handling missing data, resampling time series into different frequencies, calculating rolling/expanding-window statistics, etc.

Because it's the gold standard, many Python numerical packages work seamlessly with pandas to provide even more capabilities. For example, [statsmodels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net) is a statistical package that lets you run everything from a simple [linear regression](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/ols.html) to a complicated [dynamic factor model](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/statespace_dfm_coincident.html).

Comment: Can it estimate ARMA, GARCH, etc?

Comment: @Schmidt Take a look at http://arch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. It's very easy to use and fairly comprehensive.